# How do I set an incremental id length like this 000001, 000002,

Tags: laravel

I want would like to have an incremental id with a determined length like 0000001, 0000002, 0100000,... How am I suppose to set that. Any help will be welcomed.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('animals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
            $table->date('dateOfBirth');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('placeOfBirth');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I will leave the auto increment as it is, otherwise you will have to handle it manually which is painful.

You can create an accessor in your Animal model, for example:

```
protected $appends = ['code'];

public function getCodeAttribute()
{
    // use $this->attributes['id'] or try with $this->id
    return str_pad($this->attributes['id'], 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Then to use it:

```
Animal::first()->code;
```

Comment: So the last line I will just put it in my model?

Comment: No, that's the way you would use it.. I am just showing you an example. That you can access it as a property on the model. You might have `$animal = Animal::find(1);`  for example.. so you can use `$animal->code`